# Using mysql.connector in Python execute a MySQL Trigger that calculates and inserts a value into a newly created column in an existing table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, triggers, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying in Python 3 to execute a cursor that will create a new column "Total_TU" in a table, and this column should automatically get values for each row based on rows from other 2 columns: "CU_per_TU" and "TU".
"Total_TU" = "CU_per_TU" * "TU"

Columns "Total_TU" and "TU" are created at the same time, and I need to update the column "Total_TU" after the column "TU" is updated.

The SQL syntax error is in the last cursor.execute statement.

I'm trying this code, which I've seen in other topics and manuals, but I get an SQL syntax error for the last cursor.execute command, and I don't understand where's the problem.

Here is the code

```
import mysql.connector

conn = connection_forward_db
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AC_forwarders.table_a AS SELECT * FROM `temp`")
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE AC_forwarders.table_a ADD TU INT, ADD Total_CU INT")
cursor.execute("UPDATE table_a SET TU = "+int(x)+" WHERE Product_ID = aaa")


cursor.execute("""CREATE TRIGGER Total_TU_update BEFORE UPDATE ON table_a
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET new.Total_TU = new.CU_per_TU * new.TU;
END~

CREATE TRIGGER Total_TU_insert BEFORE INSERT ON table_a
OR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET new.Total_TU = new.CU_per_TU * new.TU; 
END~""") 

conn.commit()
```

The column Total_TU must get updated based on CU_per_TU and TU, after TU is updated with a value.

**Here is the full error**(I run only the last cursor as 3 others work fine):

MySQLInterfaceError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py in cmd_query(self, query, raw, buffered, raw_as_string)
    394                                raw=raw, buffered=buffered,
--> 395                                raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
    396         except MySQLInterfaceError as exc:

MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '~

CREATE TRIGGER Total_TU_insert BEFORE INSERT ON table_a
OR EACH ROW BEGIN
   ' at line 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     17 OR EACH ROW BEGIN
     18     SET new.Total_TU = new.CU_per_TU * new.TU;
---> 19 END~""") 
     20 
     21 conn.commit()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py in execute(self, operation, params, multi)
    264             result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,
    265                                          buffered=self._buffered,
--> 266                                          raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
    267         except MySQLInterfaceError as exc:
    268             raise errors.get_mysql_exception(msg=exc.msg, errno=exc.errno,

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py in cmd_query(self, query, raw, buffered, raw_as_string)
    396         except MySQLInterfaceError as exc:
    397             raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg,
--> 398                                              sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
    399         except AttributeError:
    400             if self._unix_socket:

ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '~

CREATE TRIGGER Total_TU_insert BEFORE INSERT ON table_a
OR EACH ROW BEGIN
' at line 4

Comment: Lets start with the syntax error - what is it?

Comment: ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '~

CREATE TRIGGER Total_TU_insert BEFORE INSERT ON table_a
OR EACH ROW BEGIN

Comment: A few observations - 1) your second trigger reads OR EACH ROW and should be FOR EACH ROW 2)The triggers are single statements you do not need begin and the end which goes with the begin 3) There is no column CU_per_TU so will throw another error when you fix the first 2. 4) there is no column called Total_TU 5) you need to set multi=true if you submit more than 1 statement at a time - Otherwise good job.

Answer (score 0):

Big Thanks to P.Salmon!

Yes, now it works after I adjusted the code:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TRIGGER Total_TU_update BEFORE UPDATE ON table_a
FOR EACH ROW
    SET new.Total_TU = new.CU_per_TU * new.TU;""")


cursor.execute("""CREATE TRIGGER Total_TU_insert BEFORE INSERT ON table_a
FOR EACH ROW
    SET new.Total_TU = new.CU_per_TU * new.TU;""") 

conn.commit()
```

P.S The other dependent columns exist in the table, I just didn't mention them, as there is no problem with them :)